# Boolean Referencing

Tags: java, arrays, boolean

I am processing lines of `txt` file which contains 4 boolean characteristics. I want to pass a boolean[] into a method with a reference to which line it came from (which line is defined by another variable on the line which is incremental, just not necessarily ordered).

Is there a way to create an array, of some sort, with a reference to the line variable and then the 4 booleans from that line?

If not directly, I can use 0 and 1 to represent false and true respectively eg. `array[i][0] = 0;`  and then transfer this into a boolean in the receiving method:

```
boolean charone = (array[i][0] == 1) ? true : false;
```

Edit: The characteristics represent whether a coordinate on the line is at a maximum of the symbol described by the whole `txt` file.

```
Pattern patternx = Pattern.compile("(?<=(<))((-)*?(\\d+))(?=(,))"); 
Pattern patterny = Pattern.compile("(?<=(,))((-)*?(\\d+))(?=(>))");

for(String pin : pins){
        boolean sidemax = false;
        boolean sidemin = false;
        boolean top = false;
        boolean bottom = false;
        int i = Integer.parseInt(pin.split(" ")[1]);
        Matcher matcherx = patternx.matcher(pin);
        Matcher matchery = patterny.matcher(pin);

        while (matcherx.find()){

            String numb = matcherx.group(0);        
            int x = Integer.parseInt(numb);

            if (x >= maxx) {
                sidemax = true;
            }
            if (x <= minx){
                sidemin = true;
            }
        }
        while (matchery.find()){

            String numb = matchery.group(0);
            int y = Integer.parseInt(numb);

            if (y >= maxy) {
                top = true;
            }
            if (y <= miny) {
                bottom = true;
            } 
        }
```

Is there a way to carry through `sidemax, sidemin, top, and bottom` into another method by adding them directly to an array of every line passed in, such that the array would be 2D with the top layer being a reference and the bottom layer being 4 booleans?

Comment: could you share a sample of txt file

Comment: would this help .. Map<Integer, List<Boolean>>  where the key is line variable and your list is the 4 boolean characterstics

Comment: It's not clear what you're looking for. Please consider improving the question.

Comment: @Sikorski please post it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java is an Object Oriented Language. Create classes to represent your data:

```
public class Line {
    private int lineNumber;
    private boolean value1;
    private boolean value2;
    private boolean value3;
    private boolean value4;

    // constructor, getters, other potential useful methods omitted
}
```

When reading the file, create instances of the above `Line` class, and pass these instances to the methods who need the 4 boolean values and the number of the line where they come from.

Comment: I need to read the booleans for each line out in the receiving method, such that creating objects for each line would be impractical and each line is read in and then the method is called so I can't create a new object for each line and close in before reading the next line.

Comment: Why couldn't you do that? Why would it be impractical? Why would creating an array be practical, but not an instance of Line?

Comment: Some of the `txt` files are >100000lines, creating objects for each line would run into memory issues, I tried.

Comment: Arrays are also classes. And they obviously consume memory as well. Creating an array or creating an instance of Line would not change anything regarding to memory consumption. The class could even use less memory, since it would use booleans instead of integers, and would not have an unneeded length attribute. BTW, 100,000 lines is nothing. It shouldn't consume more than 4 MBs to have 100,000 Line instances in memory.

Comment: I just measured. It uses less than 2 MBs.

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly, you are suggesting creating an object for each line and referencing that object in the method as opposed to creating one array object for all the `txt` file. If I have understood, could you clarify: the best way to write and reference a constructor such that each object it makes has a unique reference and also, why creating many objects take up less memory than creating one larger one. I may be misunderstanding something about Java.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. You asked how to be able to pass to methods the following information: 1 reference to a line (this is the lineNumber in the Line class), and 4 booleans (value1 to value4 in the Line class). So, each time you need to pass such a set of information, you can create an instance of Line and pass the created Line instance. If you need to keep this information for each and every line of your text file, then create an array of Line instances (`Line[]`) or a `List<Line>`. Regarding memory an array of 100,000 Line instances consumes less than 2 MBs.